# print description title tag in flex slider

Tags: nodes, javascript

I want to print image field title inside the `<img>`.

eg. `<img draggable="false" class="flex-img img-responsive" title="[description-title]" src="http:example.com/sites/default/files/styles/showcase_720/public/images/gallery/2nd%20Division%20Ileague%20Champion%20%282%29.png?itok=F6cf3dxI">`

i don't know how to do it. it print

`<img draggable="false" class="flex-img img-responsive" src="http:example.com/sites/default/files/styles/showcase_720/public/images/gallery/2nd%20Division%20Ileague%20Champion%20%282%29.png?itok=F6cf3dxI">`

Here is my code on node--gallery.tpl.php

```
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php
        $imgcount = count($node->field_gallery_images['und']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $imgcount; $i++) {
        $image_uri = $node->field_gallery_images['und'][$i]['uri'];
        // url
        $masthead_raw = image_style_url('showcase_720', $image_uri);            
    ?>

    <li data-thumb="<?php print $masthead_raw; ?>"><img class="flex-img img-responsive" src="<?php print $masthead_raw; ?>"/></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Please Help.